# Mysql complex data issue

Tags: mysql

I have an articles websites and i have a suggestion box in which i suggest read more articles. What i wanna do is suggest the most relevant quizz instead of picking random articles and showing them.
So let's assume a reader is on a article with the id no 19. In the suggestion box i want to show the articles which were read by people who also read article no 19.So if person A read 19,26,30 and person B is reading 19 so he tend most to be intersted in article no 26,30.
I have a table on which i record every article read by user with his user id.

```
ID / USER ID / ARTICLEID
1 / 30       / 10
2 / 20       / 10
3 / 20       / 80
4 / 10       / 10
5 / 20       / 60
6 / 10       / 60
7 / 20       / 80
8 / 10       / 90
```

Here is what want : GET THE ID OF THE ARTICLE THAT USER IS CURRENTLY READING -> Go to database and get id of all the users who read this article -> Get id of all articles that were read by these user -> Order them by numbers of user by article.
It is really frustrating since i do not have much mysql experience. so basic commands of select doesnt seem to work and i am asking for help or just idea and i will look to execute them.
UPDATE 1 : Output needed

- Get users IDS of users who read the article id no 10 : IDS : 30/10/20
- See which other articles were read by this users : 80(1
  user)/60(2user)/90(1user)
- So final output : ARTICLES BY ORDER : 60/90/80

Comment: post the desired output as well to see what expected as well.

Comment: @Rahul Check the update and please let me know if it is clear

Comment: It seems you need to work some mysql tutorial sites.

Comment: @Drew You should know that i have tables of 75 million records so it's not easy

Comment: I suggest lookup up how to write self-join queries.

Comment: You could have 20 rows, same deal. Create a db with few rows and learn to program with mysql. It is your 4th question here and none of them have code attempts expect the `where id=9` one. You need to do *your* part.

Comment: @belwood I dont't think self-join gonna work as long as they are not on separated tables they are boths on same tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made a sample. i am nearly sure that this is what you search.
i will describe it some pieces

**the full query**

```
SELECT count(`art_id`) as cnt, `art_id`
FROM user_art 
WHERE `user_id` in (
        SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
        FROM user_art
        WHERE `art_id` = 10 -- Current Article ID to find other user
        AND user_id <> 20   -- Current User Id to exclude from list
        )
GROUP by `art_id`
ORDER BY cnt DESC , `art_id` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Step by Step**

**the input data**

```
mysql>  SELECT * FROM user_art;
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | art_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      10 |     10 |
|  2 |      20 |     30 |
|  3 |      20 |     80 |
|  4 |      10 |     90 |
|  5 |      20 |     10 |
|  6 |      23 |     10 |
|  7 |      23 |     11 |
|  8 |      23 |     12 |
|  9 |      10 |     11 |
+----+---------+--------+
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Find all User IDs who also read sam article**

```
mysql> select DISTINCT `user_id`
    -> FROM user_art
    -> WHERE `art_id` = 10 -- Current Article ID to find other user
    -> AND user_id <> 20;  -- Current User Id to exclude from list
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|      10 |
|      23 |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**find all article that read by userlist**

find all article that read by userlist and order by count of user desc and article id desc => higher article_no = > newer article

```
mysql> SELECT count(`art_id`) as cnt, `art_id`
    -> FROM user_art
    -> WHERE `user_id` in (10,23)
    -> GROUP by `art_id`
    -> ORDER BY cnt DESC , `art_id` DESC
    -> ;
+-----+--------+
| cnt | art_id |
+-----+--------+
|   2 |     11 |
|   2 |     10 |
|   1 |     90 |
|   1 |     12 |
+-----+--------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**comination of both queries**

comination of both queries with LIMIT to get only the next article

```
mysql> SELECT count(`art_id`) as cnt, `art_id`
    -> FROM user_art
    -> WHERE `user_id` in (
    ->         SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
    ->         FROM user_art
    ->         WHERE `art_id` = 10 -- Current Article ID to find other user
    ->         AND user_id <> 20   -- Current User Id to exclude from list
    ->         )
    -> GROUP by `art_id`
    -> ORDER BY cnt DESC , `art_id` DESC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+-----+--------+
| cnt | art_id |
+-----+--------+
|   2 |     11 |
+-----+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Just perfect  bro !